# Objects appear dark

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects

The ceiling looks very dark. How can I make it light? The lamp and wall textures on the ceiling are not visible.

Work file: https://dosya.co/5u4m5wadulp1/calisma.blend.html

[image]

[image]

Ceiling shader panel

[image]

Lamp shader panel

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please show the Shader Editor or share your file?

Comment: I shared the shading panel

Comment: I also added the link of the file.

Comment: it would be helpful if you do file->external data->pack resources before uploading your file...

Comment: As Chris says, it's hard to tell because you haven't packed your images. Also, switch the Image Texture from sRGB to Non-Color for the normal maps

Comment: Even without having those textures in the file I would say, the lamps are all shining downwards and since I don't know without textures how dark or bright the floor is it's hard to tell how much light could be bouncing off there to light the ceiling. Or do you mean they are completely invisible...? Maybe because you are in _Solid View_ instead of _Material Preview_ or _Rendered View_?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I shared the ceiling and floor image now

Comment: @user17987086 Well... as I said, the lamps are shining downwards and the floor isn't very bright so I guess there's not much light bouncing off... how should the ceiling become brighter?

Comment: ...and I just realized your object is something like 11 × 22 kilometers large. I guess you need to crank up the strength of the lamps a lot to light such a vast area. Maybe you should scale everything down to more real-life dimensions...

Comment: I packed it with the images and updated the link again. @Chris

Comment: @moonboots I renewed the link and packaged it as a visual

Comment: Of all the underground garages I've seen after googling a bit, none of their lights had little flaps on the side. Remove them and you should improve the ceiling lighting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a lot of ways, to make it lighter. Gorgious already proposed one in the comments.

You can e.g. crank up the exposure in render properties/film/exposure to 5

[image]

or use the exposure node in the compositor:

[image]

or assign an emission shader via "assign" to your light bulbs.

But of course this changes the way the result will look like. And i don't know whether you want that.

Comment: It solved my film/exposure problem and I added an extra area light to all lamps, making it even more original.